# Fullpage.js works but menubar appears behind sections

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullpage.js

I implemented the fullPage.js script for fullpage srolling.

The fullpage scroll works fine. However, I'm having an issue with the menubar. I seems to appear behind the sections. Also the links don't seem te be functioning.

the html markup for my page looks like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Always force latest IE rendering engine or request Chrome Frame -->
    <meta content="IE=edge,chrome=1" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

    <!-- Use title if it's in the page YAML frontmatter -->
    <title>Adlit</title>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link href="/stylesheets/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="/stylesheets/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.fullPage.css" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/javascripts/all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#fullpage').fullpage(
        {
        anchors: ['home', 'news', 'info'],
        menu: '#menu' 
        }
       );
    }); 
    </script>
  </head>

  <body class="index">
    <div class="main">
      <nav id="menu">
        <ul>
          <li data-menuanchor="home" class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li data-menuanchor="news"><a href="#news">Nieuws</a></li>
          <li data-menuanchor="info"><a href="#info">Info</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section home">
      <div class="hero">
        <h1>Adlit, Een onderzoeksproject rond reclamewijsheid bij minderjarigen</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section news">
      <div class="grid-items">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="grid-item">
          <img src="images/logo-digital-kids-marketing.png" alt="digital kids marketing">
          <h1>Grid Item</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit. Rem, illum.</p>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="grid-item grid-item-big grid-item-image">
          <img src="images/logo-digital-kids-marketing.png" alt="digital kids marketing">
          <h1>Grid Item With an Image</h1>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, illum.</p>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section info">
      <div class="boxes">
        <div class="box">
          <p><i class="fa fa-users"></i></p>
          <h2>Wie zijn we</h2>
          <p>Non-profit an public affairs organizations need to communicate their message with a loud and clear voice</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <p><i class="fa fa-suitcase"></i></p>
          <h2>Wat doen we?</h2>
          <p>You’ll be hard-pressed to find a team more experienced building brands and websites for Democratic political campaigns. We’re design trend-setters and know political tech inside and out.          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <p><i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i></p>
          <h2>Rapporten en Publicaties</h2>
          <p>We partner with agencies all the time to expand their services for their own clients. We fit in seamlessly. We can also do the same with your startup to get your big idea from “dream” to “reality”.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box">
          <p><i class="fa fa-university"></i></p>
           <h2>Valorizatie tools</h2>
          <p>We can leverage our extensive experience in design, tech and brand strategy to promote your idea or product. Whether it’s a campaign, an org or you’re just selling a widget, the goal of our services is always the same: to inspire.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

my styles for the menubar are:

```
nav {
  margin-top: em(20);
  margin-right: em(100);
  float: right;

  li {
    float: left;
    margin-right: em(40);
  }

  a {
    font-weight: 600;
    color: $dark-gray;

    &.active {
      padding-bottom: 2px;
      border-bottom: 3px solid $light-green; 
    }
  }
}
```

So I'm not sure what's going on. I tried to fix it by changing the z-index of my sections but this doesn't seem to have any affect. The sections appear in front of the menubar.

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Comment: We need more info. Your whole HTML structure to place your menu in the context. Or a link reproducing the problem.

Comment: Hi Alvaro, the html markup is at https://github.com/acandael/adlit/blob/onepagescroll/source/index.html.erb , the stylesheet for the homepage is at https://github.com/acandael/adlit/blob/onepagescroll/source/stylesheets/partials/_home.scss , the stylesheet for the menubar is at https://github.com/acandael/adlit/blob/onepagescroll/source/stylesheets/partials/_nav.scss . I'll see if I can deploy the site on a temporary location, so you can see the issue live. Is that enough information? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I don't see your menu in the HTML markup.

Comment: the menubar is in a partial file https://github.com/acandael/adlit/blob/onepagescroll/source/partials/_nav.erb , it then get's injected in the layout file: https://github.com/acandael/adlit/blob/onepagescroll/source/layouts/layout.erb

Comment: Just paste the generated HTML somewhere. Make it easy.

Comment: ok, I have added all mark-up in the above question.

Comment: I think I solved the issue by giving the menu element a positioning value of 'absolute' and then setting the z-index to some value like '9999'. Now the menubar appear on top of the sections and the links are working